# How to fix: Having to manually set h-100 to HTML and BODY tag. AND centering issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

If I do not set my HTML and BODY tag class = "h-100" They are showing at like 210 pixels. I then have to keep setting lower level elements to h-100 also.

I'm really not sure how to fix it other than adding the h-100

```html
<html class="h-100" lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>  index  </title>
  </head>
  <body class="h-100">
```

I believe that the correct result of bootstrap HTML and body is that it should size it self roughly to the size of the viewing medium.

Here is the full page of what I'm trying to accomplish on jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/v2cqh3n8/

The reason I am trying to have the body set to a nice size is because I want to center align the login form. Which I am also having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Try this bootstrap solution. Hope it works better for you, without adding height to BODY and HTML Tag .

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Password</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Log-in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you actually run this code i think you'e going to have the same issue that it's centered yes. But it's not jutsified. and the reason its not justified is because it's only setting the height to 210 pixels

Answer (score 0):

It worked by simply adding height to body in vh unit.  `h-100 justify-content-center` to .row

Here is working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/faocwnp6/1/

Comment: Right, but the issue with that is your constantly left with having to manually set the height to 100% of the viewport. However I think you could imagine situations where you dont want that? In general looking at the boostrap docs, I dont think that body should have to bet set h-100 and more importantly I believe its bad practice. Take a look at this which I've found in the past 5 minutes view-source:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sign-in/

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is put the form in the centre of the page, just use flexbox.
I've added in you js fiddle with the correct bootstrap classes.

The reason you need to set h-100 on these elements is that the content within those elements is not filling the DOM.

Side-note: You also don't need all of the containers/rows if you're just centering the element.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="h-100" lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>  index  </title>
  </head>
  <body class="h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">


            <form action="/login" method="POST" class="w-50">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username-input"> Username </label>
                    <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="username-input" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for-"password-inpiut"> Password </label>
                    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password-input" placeholder="Password">
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Log-in </button>
            </form>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the height of the `html` and `body` to `100%` using css or `h-100` classes and then add `d-flex` and `align-items-center` classes to the body.

```css
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title> index </title>
</head>
<body class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <form action="/login" method="POST" class="w-50 mx-auto">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username-input"> Username </label>
                        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="username-input"
                            placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password-inpiut"> Password </label>
                        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password-input"
                            placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Log-in </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code is centered. But it is not justified, nor is the body sized correctly which should be much larger than 210 pixels

Comment: @muhmmad I am OP :v. But hey man i just want you to know do really appreciate your help. I think what im looking for is something different. If this is irking you let me know and maybe I'll just try to clarify what I ment better. Take a look at this. https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/vl4R7 I really want it to be a well centered form.

Comment: @JonDoe what you want to be 210 pixels? the height or the width of the form? what I get from your question is that you want to center the form vertically and horizontally.